# Manupulate the full Row of a tiddle with 2 loops

Tags: r, tibble

first, this is a homework question.
It's easy to manipulate the full row with:

```
testMan[2,] = apply(testMan[2,], 2, function(x) 100)
```

But we have to do this in a loop and it must be a function with a parameter.

```
  manipulateRow = function(rowNumber){
  i = 1;
  for(row in testMan){
    #print(i)
    if(i == rowNumber){
      for(price in row){
        price = 100
      }
      break;
    }
    i = i + 1;
  }
}
test = manipulateRow(2);
```

The goal is to replace the full 2nd line with the value 100.
There are more than 600 columns, so we have to do it with a loop.
We are working with tibble and tiddyverse.

Comment: Your problem objective is not very clear.  But for starters, please go and review the construction of a `for` loop. For example: `for(price in row)` ,  "row" is not a sequence but a single number, the loop will run only 1 time.  Generally it should be  `for(price in 1:row)`

Comment: That is quite easy. Since it is a homework try to do it yourself. Some small hints:
(I) think about `1:nrow()`and its column aquivalent, (II) what additional arguments does the function need to work in any case, not just a special case, (III) think about a better alternative for `break`